# Unexpected token when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

friends

This is my code

```
var j = '[{"id":"151","name":"As aventuras de PI","picture":null}]'
JSON.parse(j)
```

and it keeps saying "unexpected token"

This happens in the main page of my website. But in many other pages it works fine and I use the same functions (in PHP and in Javascript) to generate this string

Whats wrong with my JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saved the file as UTF-8 without BOM (used Notepad++ for that) and that fixed the error

Answer (score 5):

You have a non-printing character between `'` and `[`.

Copy/pasting your code to jsbin makes it visible:

[image: Code screenshot]

Delete those three characters and retype them.

Comment: how could this character be added??

Comment: I have no idea what process you use to write your JSON so any speculation I might make would be wilder than usual.

Comment: @Quentin how did you manage to see the red dot? i solved the problem, but I cant see it when I go to jsbin and paste it

Comment: @VictorFerreira — I just copy/pasted it from the code in your question.

Comment: weird, I can't see it. and if I change the last line to `alert(JSON.parse(j))` it alerts an object and triggers no errors.